# Exporting table and data gives an Error >relative path not allowed for COPY to file in POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

I would like to do an Export of a table from Postgres.
Its giving me a "relative path" error. Can anyone let me know where the exported file should be saved?

Used the following sql statement

```
COPY Table_1 TO 'C:/temp/table_1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

Comment: What operating system is your server on? Are you sure it is a Windows machine?

Comment: Did you try using (escaped) backslashes instead of forward slashes?

Comment: The operating system is Linux.Tried using (escaped) backslashes but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

`COPY` writes to a file on the database server. Your database server must have an operating system different from Windows, so it doesn't recognize `C:/temp/table_1.csv` as an absolute path. Indeed, that path wouldn't make sense on an operating system different from Windows.

If you want to export a table to a file on the *client* machine, you need to use the `psql` command line client. Then you can use

```bash
\copy table_1 TO 'C:/temp/table_1.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', HEADER)
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the psql command for export  in Linux.The same command is not working.

Comment: The command is `psql`, and if you don't have it in your `PATH`, use the absolute path. Besides, I though that you were using Windows on the client machine.

Comment: Iam using windows on client machine and the command above works fine.But when I test the same in Linux  finding error. psql :warning :extra commandline argument "TO" ignored ,psql :Fatel :no pg hba.conf entry for host "[localhost]",user "tablename",database "COOPY",SSL OFF.

Comment: Open a new question for that, but first you should get familiar with a Linux shell. It seems like you are running a mixture of a `psql` invocation and `COPY`, and you misspelled `COPY` on top of that.